# Chromium repeats three times search request

Tags: 14.04, chromium, browser

When I try to search something in Chromium browser, it repeats a request string three times. I have Chromium version 44.0.2403.89 and Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).

I write search request:
[image: input screenshot]

And after it press enter:
[image]

As a result I see three time repeated search request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! I found solution for my trouble. If you'll whenever meet the same trouble, I know how to fix it.

### Troubleshooting:

1. In the top right, click the Chrome menu.
2. Click settings.
3. Go to the "Search" section.
4. Click the button, that says "Manage search engines..."

In opened window I saw two different default google search settings. Which I use repeats search request three times (I don't have and ideas, what to do it request there).

He is: `https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=fflb&q=%s&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&channel=rcs`

For solve this problem I just select other normal request string. It is all.

Screen:

[image]